# Get Most Recent Post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Currently I'm trying to get only the most recent post in my index view that is marked as 'featured'.

In my controller I have

```
@featured = Post.featured
```

In my 'Post' Model I have

```
scope :featured, -> { where(:featured => true) }
```

And in my view I have

```
  <% @featured.each do |post| %>
   <%= post.title %>
  <% end %>
```

What I'm trying to do is literally just get the first post that is marked as featured.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
@featured = Post.featured.order("created_at").last
```

Note: if you're only storing one featured post in the @featured instance variable then you can change your view code to this:

```
<%= @featured.title %>
```

It isn't necessary to loop over one item with the each method.

Comment: Do I have to remove the each loop within the view?

Comment: You don't have to but it's not really necessary to loop over one entry.

Comment: With this snipper I get the same error? undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x007f09064bb188>

Comment: Try getting rid of the loop and just displaying @featured.title in your view